# What does durability do?

Tags: diablo-iii

With Hell mode, I have grown accustomed the yellow icon signifying breaking or broken gear. Durability appears as a stat on almost all items, but what is its effect? **Are the item's stats reduced as durability decreases, or when the yellow broken man shows?** Is there any incentive for keeping everything repaired? Are completely broken items totally useless until they're repaired, or do they have partial effects? And how fast do items lose durability under normal use?

[image: yellow man]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Durability is the current condition of your armor or weapon. The number can be found in the bottom right corner of an item description, reading X/Y, where X is the current and Y is the maximum.

When this number reaches zero, your item breaks, causing you to lose any bonuses or visual effects said item may have given. Until you repair it, that is. The only time the durability has any effect on the stats from the item is when the item is fully broken (at 0 durability). Until that time, you will still reap the full benefits of that item.

The main benefit to keeping everything fully repaired is that you can quest for extensive periods of time without worrying about any of your gear breaking. It can also help you during boss battles when in a group, as it gives you some leeway in the number of deaths you can handle before your equipment is completely ruined during that fight. Generally, I make it a habit to check my need for repairs upon every visit to town. The sooner you repair an item, the less costly it will be to both your wallet, and your life.

Comment: Incomplete answer, lacks information about "how fast do items lose durability under normal use?"

Comment: @NickT I chose not to answer that portion for two reasons: a) There were several questions here that could have easily been standalone questions, and b) "normal use" is far too subjective for a game like Diablo 3.