# What is the effect of low durability in Diablo-3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does durability do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68075/what-does-durability-do)

I noticed that I have to repair my weapons every so often (as I am now above level 10), and I was wondering how the durability percentage affects the weapon, if at all.

Is it something like:
100%- no effect
80%- 10% damage reduction
60%- 20% damage reduction
etc.

Or does the weapon just break when the durability reaches zero with no effect on the weapon before it reaches this point?

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/does-it-matter-when-i-repair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as in Diablo II. There are no reductions, the item just becomes unusable once the durability reaches zero.